# Linux script to extract usernames from text file

Tags: ubuntu, bash

I am a beginner at scripting, but I created a text file called `text.dat` which contains only usernames in the file location `/home/daniel/text.dat` and I’m trying to run a script(called `addusers.sh`) which displays the names from that text file and will create a new user account on the system for each new user account specified in the `text.dat` file.

For each user account that is created, append a line entry to the `/home/daniel/logs/useraccounts.log` file. The line entry will contain the following information:

```
added | < user account name > | < day and time of creation >
```

. This is what I have so far:

```
 #!/bin/bash 
echo “cat text.dat” 
newuser= grep /home/daniel/text.dat 
sudo adduser $newuser
```

Comment: Are you adding these users interactively,  (ie answering the prompts for user info), or non-interactively?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## How can I add users to a Linux system, as listed in a file?

Something along the lines of the following should do if you want the process to be fully automated (run via eg `sudo ./addusers.sh`):

```
#!/bin/bash
# addusers.sh - Add users to system and output a log of same
# run as root or via sudo

usersfile=/home/daniel/text.dat
logfile=/home/daniel/logs/useraccounts.log

while read user; do
   echo "Adding $user"
   adduser --gecos "" --disabled-password $user
   echo "added | $user | `date` |" >> $logfile
done < $usersfile
```

With options (from the `adduser` manpage):

> **`--disabled-password`**
>
> `Like --disabled-login, but logins are still possible (for example using SSH RSA keys) but not using`
> password authentication.

*(`--disabled-login` would work too I guess)*

> **`--gecos GECOS`**
>
> `Set  the  gecos  field for the new entry generated.  adduser will not ask for finger information if this option is given.`

You can leave these options to `adduser` off if you want to specify a password and/or user info.

You can also specify how you want the *day and time of creation* specified via options to `date`, eg

```
$ date "+%Y-%m-%d %H%M"
2017-02-19 0330
```

Comment: thanks so much for your answer, mostly everything went through but when I ran the script it said ./addusers.sh: line 7: /home/daniel/logs/useraccounts.log:Permission denied adding user account. I also added sudo in front of adduser in the script. Do you know why that would be?

Comment: @DanielWilson it sounds like the line before `done < $usersfile` is causing a problem; though it works in my (minimal) example. Have you checked the logs file/directory exists and has sensible permissions?

Answer (score 0):

The event you want to log is already being logged by Linux. Take a look at `/var/log/auth.log` and try to filter or parse it according to your particular need instead of trying to create your own log file.

Here's a sampling of the log in question:

```
Feb 19 10:23:47 localhost sudo:    larssend : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/home/larssend ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/useradd -m -s /bin/bash -U tst
Feb 19 10:23:47 localhost sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Feb 19 10:23:47 localhost useradd[1661]: new group: name=tst, GID=1001
Feb 19 10:23:47 localhost useradd[1661]: new user: name=tst, UID=1001, GID=1001, home=/home/tst, shell=/bin/bash
Feb 19 10:23:48 localhost sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Feb 19 10:23:50 localhost sudo:    larssend : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/home/larssend ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/userdel -r tst
Feb 19 10:23:50 localhost sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Feb 19 10:23:50 localhost userdel[1667]: delete user 'tst'
Feb 19 10:23:50 localhost userdel[1667]: removed group 'tst' owned by 'tst'
Feb 19 10:23:50 localhost userdel[1667]: removed shadow group 'tst' owned by 'tst'
Feb 19 10:23:50 localhost sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
```

As you can see, it has pretty much everything you might need to know about user account creation and deletion, including *who* performed the creation/deletion by way of `sudo` logging. Note that if the creator didn't use `sudo` to call `useradd` or `userdel`, you may have to perform some extra work to figure out who performed the creation/deletion.

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question. OP is trying to **create** new accounts himself not log existing creations.

Comment: @DavidPostill: "For each user account that is created, append a line entry to the /home/daniel/logs/useraccounts.log file." I was advising against exactly that.